# How to calculate filtered file size in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a folder hierarchy Bucket/folder/year/month/date/files.ext e.g 2021/12/31/abc.html and  2022/1/1/file1.html etc. The folder contains millions of html files and images. I only want to calculate the sum of size filtered by .html extensions only, the year will start from 2019 to 2022 and for each month and date.
right now what I'm using

```
gsutil du gs://Bucket/folder/*/*/*/*.html | wc -l
```

I couldn't find any better solution it is taking too long and gives the connection to your Google Cloud Shell was lost. And second thing is that I want to delete all html files in 2019/1/1/file1.html

Comment: Can you please try the following command `gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name | find . -name "*.html" | xargs du -sch`

Comment: your command gives
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you're already looking at the right answer. GCS doesn't provide any sort of index that'll quickly calculate total file size by file type.

Cloud Shell will time out after some minutes of inactivity, or after 24 total hours, so if you have millions of files and need this to complete, I would suggest starting a small GCE instance and running the command from there, or running gsutil from your own machine.